# Sequel Pro - How to reading in Characters like Ö, ü, ç, ñ, ß

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am reading in data to MySQL using Sequel Pro but it won't reading in special characters like `Ö, ü, ç, ñ, ß`. I tried `Western ISO Latin 1`, that doesn't work. I also tried `Western DOS Latin 1`, that actually converts these characters to something else. Is there a way to preserve the original characters and don't change them when importing the data?

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); // assuming mysqli and connection name of $conn
```

There are variations for the mysql (depreciated) drivers and PDO as well.

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
$dbh -> exec("set names utf8"); // assuming a connection string of $dbh
```

Comment: I typed `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8")` into the console, but it says there is a syntax error. Is this something I need to type in to the terminal window?

Comment: I also recreated the database using `utf-8`, then load the data, and getting error `utf-8 conversion error`. :( How can I load these data into the database...